# Trouble with calling methods in java

Tags: java, methods, primes

Okay, I'm trying to write a program that does three things. Ask the user to enter three numbers. The next thing is I want is to call a method to sum these numbers and display them. Then I want to call another method to determine if the sum is prime. Now, I know how to do almost all of this, except I'm not sure I understand how to call a new method, and what the purpose is. I can write a program that does all three steps, but without calling to a new method each time. How would I do that? And what is the purpose of doing it like that instead of all just under the main method?

If you need me to post the code for the three steps I can, also thanks for any help!

edit: here is my code so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Ask for numbers
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int num3 = scan.nextInt();

    int sum = sum(num1, num2, num3);
    System.out.println(sum);

    boolean isPrime = isPrime(sum); 


}

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3) {

        int sum = 0;

        sum = (number1 + number2 + number3);

        return sum; 
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int sum) {

        boolean prime = true;
        for(int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
            if(sum % p == 0)
                prime = false;

        }
    }
}
```

The two things I'm confused on is how to figure out prime and return result in the last method, and I also don't fully understand the point of these extra methods. I believe after I can return result then I can print.out the results in the main, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Edit2: For anyone looking later, I figured it out I believe, here is my updated code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Ask for numbers
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1 = scan.nextInt();
    int num2 = scan.nextInt();
    int num3 = scan.nextInt();

    int sum = sum(num1, num2, num3);
    System.out.println("The sum of your numbers is " + sum + ".");

    boolean isPrime = isPrime(sum); 
    if (isPrime)
        System.out.println("\nThe sum is a prime number.");
    else 
        System.out.println("\nThe sum is not a prime number.");



}

    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3) {

        int sum = 0;

        sum = (number1 + number2 + number3);

        return sum; 
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int sum) {

        boolean isprime = true;
        for(int p = 2; p < sum; p++) {
            if(sum % p == 0)
                isprime = false;    
        }
        return isprime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far.  If you have a specific problem getting some of it to work, we can help you with that.  If you have a general "I don't know how to do this" problem, please find a tutorial.  We don't provide that kind of thing here.

Comment: We are not here to solve your homework for you. At least show us what you already have.

Comment: You should always post the code.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the method is at these 2 lines:

```
int sum = sum (num1, num2, num3);
```

and

```
boolean isPrime = isPrime(sum);
```

What it does is call on the methods then the value which is returned in the called method is stored in the variable before the method call(sum and isPrime);

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("In the main method");
        /*
         * Get the users input (3 numbers)
         */

        int sum = sum(num1, num2, num3);//This will call the sum method which will calculate the sum and return it(store it in this sum variable)

        boolean isPrime = isPrime(sum);//Calls on the 'isPrime(...)' method Stores true if sum is prime, false otherwise. 

    }
    /**
     * Calculates the sum of a 3 numbers
     * 
     * @param number1
     * @param number2
     * @param number3
     * @return sum The sum of 3 numbers
     */
    public static int sum(int number1, int number2, int number3) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        /*
         * Calculate the sum
         */
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if a number is a prime
     * 
     * @param sum   variable which is being checked for prime
     * @return true If the sum is a prime
     */
    public static boolean isPrime(int sum) {
        /*
         * Determine if the sum is a prime
         */
        return true;//Or false depending if it is a prime
    }
}
```